# Protected routes or urls functionality using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to create a protected route/url functionality using Javascript?

**For example:**

The website: `mysite.com`.

Protected urls: `mysite.com/admin/PageA` , `mysite.com/admin/PageB` or `mysite.com/adimin/PageC`

**Functionalities:**

1. If a user in not logged in and if he wants to visit any of the protected url ( for example: `mysite.com/admin/PageB`)then he should be redirected to the `mysite.com/login`.
2. Upon successful login he should be redirected back to the page he wanted to visit.

*(Couldn't find any tutorial. Please provide link if you know)*

Comment: Like React Router? Are you trying to write your own routing solution?

Comment: @Manas ... Yes, but not for React. (I have edited the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Without React

Implement a history module like this

```
export type HistoryHandle = {
  window: Object,
};

export const actions = {
  PUSH: 'HISTORY:PUSH',
  POP: 'HISTORY:POP',
};

const HISTORY_STATE_CHANGE = 'HistoryStateChange';

export const listen = (
  handle: HistoryHandle,
  callback: (location: string, action: string) => any,
)) => {
  const listener = e => {
    callback(window.location.pathname, e.detail);
  };
  handle.window.addEventListener(HISTORY_STATE_CHANGE, listener);
  return () => {
    handle.window.removeEventListener(HISTORY_STATE_CHANGE, listener);
  };
};

export const push = (
  handle: any,
  route: string,
  state?: Object,
  title?: string,
) => {
  handle.window.history.pushState(state, title, route);
  handle.window.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent(HISTORY_STATE_CHANGE, { detail: actions.PUSH }),
  );
};

let initialized = false;
export function init(window: Object): HistoryHandle {
  const handle = { window };
  if (initialized) {
    return handle;
  }
  handle.window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
    handle.window.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent(HISTORY_STATE_CHANGE, { detail: actions.POP }),
    );
  });
  initialized = true;
  return handle;
}
```

With a History module in place you can listen for changes

```
listen().then(changedPath => {
  const match = routes.filter(r => {
    return r.path === changedPath;
  }); // Make sure you render a 404 if the filter doesn't return any matched route

  return match.enter().then(isAuthenicated => {
    return { component: match.component };
  });
});
```

Where each route has a `enter` hook just like React Router.

```
const protectedRoute = {
  path: '/dashboard',
  component: Dashboard,
  enter() {
    return isUserLoggedInPromise()
  }
}
```

### Using React

You could implement your own simple React Router with something like this

```
class MyRouter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      component: Root
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  }
  ...
}
```

Now the challenge is that we can listen on history pop state not on push. This is why we'll need the History module above. So you'll have to implement a Link component first. So that you can trap push and pop state actions. For brevity, I have kept the implementation of the history API out of the answer.

```
export function Link(props: {
  to: string,
  onClick: (e: Event) => ?boolean,
  children: React.Node,
}) {
  const { to, onClick, children } = props;
  function handleOnClick(e: Event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const history = History.init(window);
      History.push(history, to);
    }
    onClick && onClick(e);
  }

  return (
    <a href={to} onClick={handleOnClick}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
}
```

Once we have a way, we can modify our MyRouter.componentDidMount as follows

```
 componentDidMount() {
    // For brevity, I'm keep the implementation of listen out of this answer.
    listen().then(changedPath => {
      // With listen in place, now its all a matter of accepting routes in props.
      const { routes } = this.props;
      const match = routes.filter(r => {
        return r.path === changedPath;
      }); // Make sure you render a 404 if the filter doesn't return any matched route

      this.setState(() => {
        return { component: match.component };
      });
    });
  }


  render() {
     return this.state.component;
  }
```

To apply authentication, the route could also pass an enter hook like React Router does.

```
const protectedRoute = {
  path: '/dashboard',
  component: Dashboard,
  enter() {
    return isUserLoggedInPromise()
  }
}
```

So, modify componentDidMount as follows:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // For brevity, I'm keep the implementation of listen out of this answer.
    listen().then(changedPath => {
      // With listen in place, now its all a matter of accepting routes in props.
      const { routes } = this.props;
      const match = routes.filter(r => {
        return r.path === changedPath;
      }); // Make sure you render a 404 if the filter doesn't return any matched route

      match.enter().then(isAuthenicated => {
        this.setState(() => {
          return { component: match.component };
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Let me know if you'd like more clarification on anything here :)

Comment: Ya, sure. Thanks for the effort :)